# Firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0 is not working

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter, dart

I try to setup push notifications on iOS with firebase_messaging 9.0.0. After running flutter pub get, I got an output like this

```
*Running "flutter pub get" in x-y-app...                         
    Because firebase_messaging >=9.0.0 depends on firebase_messaging_platform_interface ^2.0.0 which depends on plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0, firebase_messaging >=9.0.0 requires plugin_platform_interface ^2.0.0. (1) So, because path_provider_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on plugin_platform_interface ^1.0.1, firebase_messaging >=9.0.0 is incompatible with path_provider_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety.
    Because shared_preferences_linux >=0.0.4-nullsafety <2.0.0 depends on shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety and shared_preferences_linux >=0.0.2+1 <0.0.4-nullsafety depends on path_provider_linux ^0.0.1, shared_preferences_linux >=0.0.2+1 <2.0.0 requires shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety or path_provider_linux ^0.0.1.
    And because shared_preferences_linux <=0.0.2 depends on path_provider ^1.6.11 which depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1, shared_preferences_linux <2.0.0 requires shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety or path_provider_linux ^0.0.1 or path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
    And because path_provider_linux <0.2.0-nullsafety depends on path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1 and shared_preferences >=0.5.8 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on shared_preferences_linux ^0.0.2, shared_preferences >=0.5.8 <2.0.0-nullsafety requires shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety or path_provider_platform_interface ^1.0.1.
    And because firebase_messaging >=9.0.0 is incompatible with path_provider_platform_interface <2.0.0-nullsafety (1), if firebase_messaging >=9.0.0 and shared_preferences >=0.5.8 <2.0.0-nullsafety then shared_preferences_platform_interface ^2.0.0-nullsafety.
    And because shared_preferences >=0.5.4+8 <2.0.0-nullsafety depends on shared_preferences_platform_interface ^1.0.0, firebase_messaging
>=9.0.0 is incompatible with shared_preferences >=0.5.8 <2.0.0-nullsafety.
    So, because xyapp depends on both shared_preferences ^0.5.10 and firebase_messaging ^9.0.0, version solving failed. pub get failed (1;  So, because xyapp depends on both shared_preferences ^0.5.10 and firebase_messaging ^9.0.0, version solving failed.) exit code 1*
```

What will I do to make this work? here is my flutter doctor

```
*[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.1, on Mac OS X 10.15.7 19H512 darwin-x64, locale en)
    • Flutter version 2.0.1 at /Users/kk41/Desktop/flutter
    • Framework revision c5a4b4029c (8 days ago), 2021-03-04 09:47:48 -0800
    • Engine revision 40441def69
    • Dart version 2.12.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.2)
    • Android SDK at /Users/kk41/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.2
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 12.4, Build version 12D4e
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 4.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b3-6222593)

[✓] IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition (version 2020.2.2)
    • IntelliJ at /Applications/IntelliJ IDEA CE.app
    • Flutter plugin version 50.0
    • Dart plugin version 202.7319.5

[✓] Connected device (3 available)
    • iPhone (mobile)    • eedacda643584e88f67338d4a3599f82f9edae23 • ios            • iOS 14.4
    • iPhone 11 (mobile) • 74DE1CA1-78B6-4FE4-87CF-5F518921B7F1     • ios            • com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-14-4 (simulator)
    • Chrome (web)       • chrome                                   • web-javascript • Google Chrome 89.0.4389.82

• No issues found!*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue occurs when you are using the versions of differently libraries which are in conflict with each other for example in your case `firebase_messaging` and `shared_preferences` are in conflict along with many others. I would suggest you to either downgrade the version of `firebase_messaging` to version `^7.0.x` or to update the each conflicting library to their latest versions.

Also to mention that `firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0` is still in development as of now so it is always better to use the stable versions.

Comment: Thanks for the response! by the way how to know if that certain package is still in development? @Saheb Singh

Comment: You can find here https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_messaging/versions

Answer (score 1):

I have faced this issue yesterday. Since Firebase upgraded their packages this week most packages are incompatible with them so I solved the issue by downgrading the Firebase packages to the previous versions. Use the following versions
firebase_messaging: ^7.0.3
firebase_core: ^0.7.0
shared_preferences: ^2.0.4
http: ^0.12.2
connectivity: ^2.0.2

Answer (score 0):

I have had the package versions issue so I upgraded all packages.As I see we use some common packages so I will share my dependencies below, many of then are not in a stable version. This works for me, hope I helped!

```
  cupertino_icons: ^1.0.0
  intl: ^0.17.0
  sqflite: ^1.3.2+2
  logging: ^0.11.4
  shared_preferences: ^2.0.4
  http: ^0.12.2
  args: ^2.0.0
  path_provider: ^2.0.1
  page_transition: ^1.1.7+6
  easy_localization: 3.0.0
  connectivity: ^3.0.2
  fluttertoast: ^7.1.6
  convert: ^2.1.1
  encrypt: ^5.0.0-beta.1
  flutter_html: ^1.2.0
  settings_ui: ^0.5.0
  table_calendar: ^2.3.3
  flutter_calendar_carousel: ^1.5.3
  platform_date_picker: ^0.0.4+1

  flutter_svg: ^0.20.0-nullsafety.3
  flutter_local_notifications_platform_interface: 3.0.0-nullsafety.4
  flutter_local_notifications: ^5.0.0-nullsafety.1

  firebase_messaging: ^9.0.0
  firebase_analytics: ^7.1.1
  firebase_core: ^1.0.1
  plugin_platform_interface: ^2.0.0
```

Comment: flutter pub upgrade is always a great solution. Like unplugging and plugging something back.

Answer (score 0):

Its a conflict issue make sure all other plugin are upto date flutter should come up with better error messages.